# Javascript popup window only popping once per page load

Tags: javascript, popup, forms

When I submit my form, a window to another URL pops up. If I close the popup and resubit the form, the window opens in a new tab until I reload the page. How can I make the window open in a popup every time, without reloading the page?

```
<form action="http://stackoverflow.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="imgform" onsubmit="process(); return false;">
    // FORM PARAMS
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript function:

```
process = function(){
    popWindow = window.open('','popup','width=800,height=600,resizable=yes');
    document.imgform.setAttribute('target','popup');
    document.imgform.setAttribute('onsubmit','');
    document.imgform.submit();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete `document.imgform.setAttribute('onsubmit','');`

Answer (score 1):

on this line:

`document.imgform.setAttribute('onsubmit','');`

you are clearing the javascript call to your `process` function which opens the popup. have you tried just removing this line?